# Bootstrap with Offcanvas - 1 Menu, 2 Buttons to open the Menu with data-target

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, off-canvas-menu

have a problem with Bootstraps data-target/data-toggle and Offcanvas for sliding-in the Nav.
My code you can see here http://modus-media.de/kunden/test/.

This layout has to be created and I have the DIV ".bar" load at two different locations, which brings me to my problem the.

The button for calling my navigation is loaded once in the "header" and once outside. In the header it only appears from (min-width: 568px)-> so hidden-xs and outside (max-width: 568px) -> hidden-sm.
The function only works for the first button.

My success was so far limited. I tested it with data-parents and data-targets.

Is it possible to place a button twice, so that the menu can be accessed and if so, how?
Or is there a better way for the menu inside and outside the `<header>`?

Maybe someone can help me. Thanks in advance